# Formula - Bounce height with respect to time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I'm trying to graph a bounce with respect to time. I have these formulas:

$\frac 12 mV_2^2 = mgH_2$

and

$H_2 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{V_2^2}{g}$

I will have a series of $H(t)$ formulas as I know how to get the next bounce's initial velocity (last bounce's final velocity * -(coefficient of restitution)).

Is there a way to get an H(t) formula from these? I am not a physicist, but a computer science teacher. I have thoughts, but I am not sciencey enough to figure it out.

Thoughts:

Velocity is distance / time (position? / time). Would that mean that:

$\frac 12 mV_2^2 = mgH_2$ =>

$mV_2^2 = 2mgH_2$ =>

$V_2^2 = 2gH_2$ =>

$V_2 = \sqrt{2gH_2}$ =>

$d/t = \sqrt{2gH_2}$ =>

$d = \frac{\sqrt{2gH_2}}{t}$

Does that work?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic.

Comment: it doesnt work because the speed is not constant, so you cannot define it as $d/t$. I already pointed you to the correct equation in your previous question and gave you a reference, what part did you do not understand?

Comment: For one thing, you didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Jeff: please don't use emotive straw men. Bruce never said anything of the sort.

Comment: He did, just deleted his comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to notice that this motion is accelerated, so if you define velocity as $d/t$ you will get the wrong result. For uniformly accelerated motion (which is your case, the acceleration is contant: g), you have to use the following relationship:

$y(t)=y_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

When you release the ball, $y_0=H$, $v_0=0$ and $a=-g$ so you get $ y(t)=H-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$.
After  the first bounce you get, for each bounce:
 $y(t)= v_{bounce}t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$

The graphic is a series of inverted parabolas, there is no single formula to encompass the entire curve. You have to define it piecewise.

Comment: So, my first formula will be different from the subsequent bounces, right? and $v_{bounce}$ is the initial velocity leaving the ground, right?

Comment: just a clarification, H is the initial release height, not the height after each bounce.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in th previous expression, $v_{bounce}=e^n\sqrt{2H/g}$, for the $n^{th}$ bounce

Comment: Th reason being that the ball returns to the ground with the same speed it left, and after the bounce will be reduced by  a factor $e$ (coefficient of restitution, not the number e)

Comment: You are welcomed, and I apologize if I sounded mean, it was not my intention.